# Getting Error When access the com port With blazor

Tags: blazor-webassembly, serial-communication, com-port

[It Will Gives The Error When Access the COM Port Using the System.IO.Port [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07TkV.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straight forward. You can't use System.IO.Ports in Blazor Wasm. It only works in a Windows environment. Using a browser on Windows doesn't make it execute in a Windows environment.

Browsers are restrictive when it comes to local resources.

This might help?

https://www.janduniec.blog/index.php/284/serial-port-operation-in-blazor-wasm/